# How to debug test data generated by a data service in UWP Windows 10

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm-light, win-universal-app, uwp

I've got UWP App which uses MVVMLight and a data service which is injected in my ViewModel's constructor and the data service works fine at run-time. It pulls data from a web service, but I can't get it to work when I'm trying to build some test data so I can play around with the UI in debug mode while in the IDE.

Here's what I'm using:

**ViewModelLocator:**

```
if (ViewModelBase.IsInDesignModeStatic)
  {
    SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IDataService,
    Design.DesignDataService>();
  }
else
  {
    SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IDataService>(() => new DataService());
  }
```

**DesignDataService:**

```
public class DesignDataService : IDataService
{
    public bool IsConnectedToInternet
    {
        get
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public Task<T> DownloadDataAsync<T>(string url)
    {
        switch (url)
        {
            case Urls.Data1Url:
                return Task.FromResult<T>(GetData1<T>());
            default:
                return Task.FromResult<T>(default(T));
        }
    }
}

private T GetData1<T>()
{
    ObservableCollection<Data1Model> items = new
            ObservableCollection<Data1Model>();

    items.Add(new Data1Model(){Name="Test1"});
    items.Add(new Data1Model(){Name="Test2"});

    return (T) Convert.ChangeType(items, typeof(T));
}
```

**Data1PageViewModel:**

```
this.TemporaryItems = new ObservableCollection<Data1Model>();
this.Items = this.Items ?? (this.Items = new
             ObservableCollection<Data1Model>());
this.Items.Clear();

if (this.IsInDesignMode)
  {
    this.TemporaryItems = 
    this.DataService.DownloadDataAsync<ObservableCollection<Data1Model>>
    (Urls.Data1Url).Result;

    foreach (Data1Model tempItem in this.TemporaryItems)
{
      this.Items.Add(tempItem);
}
  }
  else
  {
    //deal with live data
  }
```

**XAML:**

```
<Page x:Class="MyApp.Views.NowNextPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="using:MyApp.Views"
    xmlns:converters="using:MyApp.Converters"
    xmlns:usercontrols="using:MyApp.UserControls"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, 
                  Path=Data1PageViewModel}"
    SizeChanged="Page_SizeChanged"
    Loaded="Page_Loaded" >

<Grid Background="White">
    <ListView x:Name ="lvwData1"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"  
              Background="White" 
              VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
              SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedNowNextIndex, Mode=TwoWay}"
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedNowNextItem, Mode=TwoWay}"
              SelectionMode="None"
              ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListViewItemStyle}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <usercontrols:Data1UserControl />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
    <usercontrols:ProgressControl Visibility="{Binding IsLoadingData, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}" 
                                  IsDataLoading="{Binding IsLoadingData}" 
                                  ProgressMessage="{Binding ProgressMessage}" >
    </usercontrols:ProgressControl>
</Grid>
```

I've simplified the creation of my test data for this question sake and hopefully I haven't messed up any of the names, but if I have, please ignore as in my code, these are definitely correct. Remember this works as expected at run-time.

I've tried getting rid of the call to the "debugging data service" by calling a static function directly within the IsInDesignMode condition:

```
foreach (Data1Model tempItem in Design.GetData1List())
{
this.Items.Add(tempItem);
}
```

But it still won't display my data when in Design mode.

I've read this very good article:

[Windows 10 Development: Adding Design-Time Data with Blend](http://blog.falafel.com/windows-10-development-adding-design-time-data-with-blend/)

And while I'm not doing it 100% as it is done in the article, it's very similar, but I must be missing something!

Any ideas why my `ListView` is not displaying any items when in the IDE?

Is there any test I can do to check if the "IsInDesignMode" part is actually called?

Comment: I dont think the code that is run while in design mode will let you call a web service.  You should create the test data in code if you want to see test data to aid in designing the pages

Comment: @KenTucker Hi, sorry if I wasn't clear, but I'm not trying to call a web service at design time. If you look at the above code, it should call the GetData1 function at design time, which creates the data in code, not by calling the web service.

Comment: I havent used MVVMLight but when I use Models and bindings I Have my model in .cs file as propertie. I either do this this.DataContext = MyModel; or in the xaml <page DataContext="{Binding MyModel, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get data front your web service in design mode
 I think is not possible, you need to create a mock viewmodel to fill all the data in design mode with fake data.

This approach is the most easy way to see all the data in design mode.

If you don't want to create a mock viewmodel you can create a mockService  to get all fake data for testing purposes.

Usually I call all the methods to get the fake data in design mode in the constructor of my ViewModel and it works very well. I'm working in a small example to show this approach I wil share it in my repo.